# What's wrong with the following array reading function?

Tags: c, arrays

I am using a Code::Blocks compiler on Windows 7. It already gave me several problems, but never one as wierd as this one. I made a function to upload numbers in to an array. Here is the code.

```
int array_read(float array[], const int max_index)
{
int converted, index=0;
char ch='a';

printf("\nEnter up to %d numbers.\n", max_index);

while((index<=max_index)&&(ch!='$'))
{
    label:printf("Enter element[%d] or $ if finished.\n", index);
    converted=scanf(" %f", &array[index]);
    ch=getchar();
    if ((converted!=1)&&(ch!='$'))
    {
        printf("Illegal character '%c'. Try again.\n", ch);
        goto label;
    }
    else
    {
        if (ch!='$')
        {
            printf("%f OK.\n", array[index]);
            index++;
        }

    }
}
index=index-1;
return index;
}
```

It's not a very nice function, but as soon as I enter '$' or the index reaches the final number, when I execute it all it does is to print a random number without stopping. Any ideas? Cheers!!!

Comment: goto label is destroying you. Never, ever use goto. Please, my eyes are bleeding.

Comment: Code::Blocks is not a compiler; it is an IDE

Comment: No need to be so cryptic, hyde. Just say that getchar returns `int` and if you store its return on a `char` variable you might not be able too detect the end of file (EOF)

Comment: @hugomg Well, TBH, I may not remember all the details of `getchar` (it so rare for me to even read from stdin with C these days), so it's either I give vague hint, or I go read the docs myself to avoid the risk of writing some nonsense... He's better off reading them himself.

Comment: About lacking exact input and output: There's nothing in the code shown which just prints a number (random or not), and there are 3 `printf` calls in the loop, so from the wordy description it's impossible to guess what printout you are actually seeing. Please update the question with example input and output!

Comment: @hyde I know getchar returns an int. I was just getting desperate so I was trying everything possible. I also defined ch as an int and it gave the same problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: 1) In the input, what `char`s are between the floating-point numbers? 2) Show calling code's `array` and `max_index` initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Don't see anything wrong with your function, I executed your code on Linux machine with below block and gave me expected results...

Though I agree that avoid using GOTO

```
/* test.c */
#include<stdio.h>

int array_read(float array[], const int max_index)
{
int converted, index=0;
char ch='a';

printf("\nEnter up to %d numbers.\n", max_index);

while((index<=max_index)&&(ch!='$'))
{
    label:printf("Enter element[%d] or $ if finished.\n", index);
    converted=scanf(" %f", &array[index]);
    ch=getchar();
    if ((converted!=1)&&(ch!='$'))
    {
    printf("Illegal character '%c'. Try again.\n", ch);
    goto label;
    }
    else
    {
    if (ch!='$')
    {
        printf("%f OK.\n", array[index]);
        index++;
    }

    }
}
index=index-1;
return index;
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  float f[100];

  i = array_read(f,5);

  printf("return value is %d \n",i);

  return 0;
}
```

And the output is as below

```
$ gcc test.c # no compilation error
$ # for complete run entering all values till loop is over
$./a.out

Enter up to 5 numbers.
Enter element[0] or $ if finished.
2
2.000000 OK.
Enter element[1] or $ if finished.
0234.5
234.500000 OK.
Enter element[2] or $ if finished.
x23
Illegal character 'x'. Try again.
Enter element[2] or $ if finished.
23.000000 OK.
Enter element[3] or $ if finished.
d
Illegal character 'd'. Try again.
Enter element[3] or $ if finished.
-1
-1.000000 OK.
Enter element[4] or $ if finished.
234
234.000000 OK.
Enter element[5] or $ if finished.
7
7.000000 OK.
return value is 5
$

$ # terminating the loop by entering $ 
$ ./a.out

Enter up to 5 numbers.
Enter element[0] or $ if finished.
2
2.000000 OK.
Enter element[1] or $ if finished.
p
Illegal character 'p'. Try again.
Enter element[1] or $ if finished.
3
3.000000 OK.
Enter element[2] or $ if finished.
$
return value is 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently codeblocks gives problems with Windows 7 according to some internet forum.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments in C passed to functions are promoted to double, when there is no ansi C parameter specification, so, all arguments to printf or scanf must be doubles, try to change your float to double and look it working.